# confusion about NSOperationQueue working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

Apple says that 
Operation queues usually provide the threads used to run their operations. In OS X v10.6 and later, operation queues use the libdispatch library (also known as Grand Central Dispatch) to initiate the execution of their operations. As a result, operations are always executed on a separate thread, regardless of whether they are designated as concurrent or non-concurrent operations.

As far as i understood from above lines that NSOperationQueue executes operations in parallel, lets put dependency thought aside.

I need to know does really NSOperationQueue initiate all operation in parallel? Does it call
 -start method of each operation at a moment or one by one in queue order?

Comment: How have you configured the queue? Did you try testing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim has already answered, look at the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, if you set this to 1, the operations will be executed in serial.

In addition, if you are concerned about the order in which operations are executed but want to utilize parallel execution, you can set up dependencies between NSOperation objects really simple by calling `- (void)addDependency:(NSOperation *)operation`.

For example, you need that operation1 is executed BEFORE operation 2, you would to something like this:

```
NSOperation *operation1;
NSOperation *operation2;
[operation2 addDependency:operation1];
```

Comment: I added some NSInvocationOperations to operation queue.Logged time at the start and end of operations inside queue(operationCount=0) with different maxConcurrentOperationCount and found that time taken was different for different maxConcurrentOperationCount. Thanks @MeXx

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property of an NSOperationQueue - it determines how many tasks the queue is allowed to start at a time.